# How can I ignore nested parentheses when pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am having trouble ignoring nested parentheses when matching patterns. Some lines of the file have nested parentheses but other lines do not. The pattern that I want to match is (a)_b, but there are parentheses inside the a. This is my pattern now:

```
(\\(([^)]+)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\})
```

I know a way you can ignore them is if you can check if a matcher group contains a parentheses. However I do not think there is a contains method for matcher groups. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a regular expression. Skipping nested structures requires the ability to count; regexes can't count.

You need to build something that tracks the nesting.  Regexes don't have very complicated syntax; it is easy enough to write a simple parser to skip over them, counting nested parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. How can I only track the nested parentheses though? Is there a way to check if a matcher group contains something?

Comment: You can't use a regex that *mentions* parentheses to pass over matching, nested parentheses.  You might be able to write a regex to pick up the target regex by *ignoring* the contained parentheses (escaped or not), if the delimters around the regex are unique.

Comment: Don't ask me.  You're the one trying to extract it from some context.

Answer (score 0):

To **NOT** match contained nestes parenthesis_ nested curly's, do something like this

```
 #  "(\\(([^()]+)\\)_\\{([^{}]+)\\})"

 (
      \(
      ( [^()]+ )
      \)
      _
      \{
      ( [^{}]+ )
      \}
 )
```

To exclude both in both places, this

```
 #  "(\\(([^(){}]+)\\)_\\{([^(){}]+)\\})"

 (
      \(
      ( [^(){}]+ )
      \)
      _
      \{
      ( [^(){}]+ )
      \}
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to match(ignore) the nested parentheses, not NOT match them.